# CSS: Aligning to images below a flexible height content div

Tags: css, photoshop

I have a site that has a fairly complicated footer, see http://www.roadsafetyforchildren.co.uk/, not really sure how to attempt to build it:

[image: Footer]

I've split the image up into two parts, the first part below needs to be horizontally centered but sit below the content:
[image]

The second part needs to repeat horizontally but stay in line with the image above.
[image]

Therefore the two images needs to look like the first image at the top of the question.

I can match the two images up **IF** the content div above it has a fixed height. The problem is the content div **NEEDS** to be flexible to grow/shrink with the content. Therefore the image at the bottom of the content div moves up and down the page depending on the size of it.

How can I keep the two images lined up with a flexible content div above it?

P.s There's a lot of answers but don't think a few of them have understood the question.

Comment: You might want to have a look at how it's done on the site that likely inspired that design: http://www.vimeo.com/

Comment: is the content centered?

Comment: @thirydot. Firstly yep, it was inspired by that! Secondly, I can't see their css to take a look.

Comment: @davidNguyen Yep it's centered.

Comment: See http://www.roadsafetyforchildren.co.uk/ for the build in progress

Comment: could you remove the background from the image with the road, and make just the road a transparent PNG?

Comment: I've posted a link above your comment that may help to see it on screen. Didn't think of that but I don't think I could because there would still be issues with resizing the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems straight forward to me, you will need two divs:

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="inner_content">
         <!-- Append image to very bottom -->
         <img src="city" width="" height="" alt="" />
     </div>
     <!-- Background image of hills goes here -->
</div>
```

CSS is straight forward..

```
#content { width: 100%; background: url('hills.png') repeat center bottom; }
#inner_content { width: xx; margin: auto; }
```

Comment: will this mean the two images stay inline not matter what the height of the content div? Also, will the hills repeat horizontally across the entire browser window.

Comment: it should, haven't test it. the height of the content should expand inner_content while pushing the image (city image) down. since the content div takes the height of the inner content, the background should line up at the bottom nicely. the background is also centered position.

Comment: It works, great, thanks. Had to add an extra div between content and inner-content as the images weren't quite aligned horizontally so added margin to that and now everything works the way I want it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; min-height:100%;}
html { background: #color url(repeteable.jpg) center bottom repeat-x; }
body { background: white url(footer.jpg) center bottom no-repeat;}
```

Comment: I think because the image is repeatable from top to bottom (gradients) it should be repeat-y

Comment: I've made the repeatable-y bit, that works fine so please ignore that. I've updated my answer to show the two images.

Comment: change the fallowing in your css: `html {min-height:100%;} body {margin:0; min-height:100%; background-position: 50% bottom;} #body { overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: This should work fine, only the body can't have white background because it will cover the html, it should be transparent.

Comment: @Litek Although it didn't work for this situation it's proved a new way to create a sticky footer!! The background sticks to the bottom but the image at the bottom of the content doesn't line up with it.

Comment: @Litek When I opened your link the footer was stuck to the bottom of the page and the image at the bottom of the content was half way up so it didn't quite work.

Comment: @Litek, I've rephrased my question as I think we're talking about two different things.

Comment: @Rob what do you want to happen if you have very short content? You want images to be below content, in the middle of the screen or at the bottom (sticky footer)?

Comment: @Litek, thanks for the help. Just solved it. The pages will have a min-height so they won't be too short. Taught me a new way to do a sticky footer though so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `<div>` the content is in should be `height:auto` and have a background image of five or so pixels high by whatever width and should repeat-y in the css, and the `<div class="footer">` should be `float:left`. That way the footer will always be below the content, and whatever height the content is will have a repeating background.

No need to mess with PS, except to create the bg image for the content.

This would be the bg image for content div, and repeat-y so it repeats from the top down:

[image]

And the footer image:

[image]

And if you make the 'background repeat' image a png, you could make the drop shadow opaque to accommodate the change in the body bg image.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear in the question - it's more about aligning two images 1. the image at the bottom of the content... and 2. the image repeating-x across the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can position a background inside an element:

```
div#footer {
    background: url('roadpic.jpg') bottom center no-repeat;
}


<div id="content">your content goes here</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

which will keep the footer div below the content at all times.

Comment: Maybe I'm making this more complicated that it actually is. That's what I did initially but I had two background elements. One was a cut out of just the road which was positioned below the content (that worked fine) the problem came when lining it up with my horizontal image of the hills that repeats-x. When adjusting window size it doesn't stay inline with the other image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a common anchor point for both the backgrounds. Between a horizontally-resizable window and a content area that is less than 100% of the window width, the only point that can remain constant between the two containers is the horizontal centre of the body.

So your hills background will need to be centred on the body or some other container that has 100% of window width. The road image can either be fixed-position inside a fixed-width centred container (shown in the example below), or centred inside a centred variable-width container.

The resulting CSS will be something like this:

```
div#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(hills.jpg) center bottom repeat-x #fff;
}
div#content {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* background can be offset to the left or right if the width is fixed
     if not it must be centred */
  background: url(road.png) right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <p>Some content here</p>
    </div> <!-- content -->
  </div> <!-- wrapper -->
</body>
```

The backgrounds of both the containers will have same anchor point and they'll move together as the window is resized!

Because #content is a child of #wrapper, they'll remain aligned vertically because #wrapper will get taller as #content gets taller (unless #content is a float, in which case you'll have to use the :after clearing trick; or if #content is position:absolute, you'll need to align them manually or with javascript).